# Is there a convenient method converting `CGRect` from screen-space into specific view-space or vice-versa?

Tags: uikit, coordinates

There are predefined methods converting coordinates between

1. `UIView` <-> `UIWindow`
2. `UIWindow` <-> `UIScreen`

How about `UIView` <-> `UIScreen`? Is there *predefined* method in `UIKit`? I can make my own, however I want to use if there is predefined one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, UIView has the conventiently-named `convertRect:toView:` and `convertRect:fromView:` methods. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW52) for details.

Note that `[A convertRect:rect fromView:B]` and `[B convertRect:rect toView:A]` are basically equivalent, unless A or B is nil.